# A word used to mean "the ultimate answer"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

I am looking for a word that I have seen many times and that has temporarily escaped my brain. If someone was to be looking for the answer to the ultimate or existential questions (life/death/religion/higher purpose etc.), what is the word used for this answer? Not the answer itself, but a synonym for *answer* with a heavier or grander meaning. Example:

> Humans have spent millennia looking for the X to life’s greatest questions.

Comment: are you thinking of *solution*?

Comment: Or something more like *the elucidation of*?

Comment: No, it is not a word that is as commonly used as 'Solution' and no it is not 'the elucidation of'. Thank you though.

Comment: How do revelation, epiphany, or insight strike you?

Comment: No, it is more of an objective answer. An epiphany or revelation may lead me to this.

I apologise for being terrible at trying to describe this. I think "answer" is a fine synonym for this word. But to say "I discovered the answer to humanities greatest question" would probably not do the statement justice. A fancier word for 'answer' while pertaining specifically to existential/grandiose questions.

Comment: 42 [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number))

Comment: So more like *resolution* or *culmination*?

Comment: Still no, I suppose it's not a very commonly used word. I've only heard it used in philosphical terms. The XXXX to lifes great questions.

Comment: What's astonishing is that if you do a Google search for "*to lifes great questions*", there are seven pages of results and I don't think I saw a single one in which the word preceding the search phrase was not *answer(s)*.

Comment: I think this is Not Constructive. But I can't resist upvoting **42** while I vote to close the question!

Comment: Voting to close NC: this is not a question that has an objective answer (supportable with facts and argument).

Comment: Metaphysical meaning?

Answer (score 1):

How about "Holy grail"?  Any goal from a legendary quest would do, I think.

Answer (score 0):

*Clincher, decider* -- unless you're Bush 43 -- *last word* or *key*.

Answer (score 0):

There *are* single words with similar meaning, but I don't think any of them has been adopted into English.

Sanskrit has *mahasatyam*, meaning the ultimate, absolute Truth of everything. Can't quite find a Vedic source, but it's cited in several glossaries.

http://www.miraura.org/lit/skgl/skgl-12.html

Greek gives us both *epiphany*, *theophany* (or *teophany*) and *theopneusty*. The first means "seeing more", the second "seeing God", and the last means merging or being imbued by the divine.

http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Theopneusty

Is it also possible (and possibly more successful) to use the word *Tao*. This has the advantage of having been popularized by titles like "The Tao of Physics" or "The Tao of C", so it sort of conveys the intended meaning.

http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Tao

```
2.  Tao - the ultimate principle of the universe
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the ultimate answer is

> ***42***

Comment: Lol! Getting punchy, are we? :-)

Comment: Yeah, I was waiting for that. I'm not looking for the answer, rather a synonym for 'answer'. See above.

Comment: That, or the Higgs boson.

Comment: -1 As soon as I read the question, I knew someone would answer that.  If you're going to post off-topic things, why not at least make them creative?

Answer (score -2):

Could you use Facticity? This has a variety of meanings, the most prevalent being the intractable conditions of human existence.  So Humans have spent millennia looking for the facticity to life’s greatest questions, means they are looking for the definitive answer that cannot be further interpreted

Comment: This doesn't seem to fit the OP's criteria.